# Getting trouble when sending http request from one laravel project to another in same machine

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have strange issue. I have two laravel projects on the same server(local server) and I want to retrieve data from one project into another. Each project has its own database and credentials. Now about problem: When I am sending `GET/POST` request using `curl()`, another project(destination project) uses credentials of the project I am sending request from. So select statement does not work due credentials and table names mismatch. When I dumped uri and pasted it into web browser it works as expected. Now question: Why second project using database credentials(or maybe other configs too) of the project I am sending request from? What is this shared session or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a little trouble getting your question, but I am assuming you are using credentials from one project and are somehow getting a return in your other project which has different credentials. On top of that, you also have different databases. How could that be? Well to put it short, it shouldn't be. Can it be done? Yes, but you would have to do it on purpose. There is no shared session. So I would check your database connections in both projects to see if there is some overlap. If there is, check those out as your issue may be in there. If that is not the case, then check your curl request and see if you are passing the correct project credentials and are therefore getting the right result. Other than that, I would need more information to help you out.

Thanks!

And oh, are you using Laravel Passport? If not, what are you using/doing?

Comment: I need to send request and get response from one project to another using curl. Nothing more. If you have a function which sends http get/post request please post here. My version does not works. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Well, if you are using laravel and php, I would recommend using guzzle over curl. Read more about it at this link: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/. As for connecting to a different site and grabbing information, I would look into Laravel Passport: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport. This is because what  you are explaining on wanting, is an API. Look into those and I think you will be on the right path.

Comment: @gogagubi, is your issue solved? I'm running the same issue. Please share how you solved

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this problem ? 
    I faced the same situation and found solution about this. 
    Solution is to change the .env file of one project as follows.

```
change .env as follows.

DB_X_HOST="localhost"  
DB_X_DATABASE="other_project"    
DB_X_USERNAME="homestead"    
DB_X_PASSWORD="secret"    
DB_X_PORT="3306"   

change config\database.php as follows.   
'mysql' => [   
  'driver' => 'mysql',   
  'host' => env('DB_X_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),   
  'port' => env('DB_X_PORT', '3306'),    
  'database' => env('DB_X_DATABASE', 'forge'),   
  'username' => env('DB_X_USERNAME', 'forge'),   
  'password' => env('DB_X_PASSWORD', ''),    
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',   
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',  
  'prefix' => '',  
  'strict' => true,  
  'engine' => null,  
]
```

It worked fine for me.