# Issue when make Guzzle Http call from one laravel app to another on same system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I'm facing a strange bug in laravel with Guzzle HTTP. I have 2 applications APP1 (act as client) and APP2 (act as server) in my localhost. The APP1 has to call APP2 by Guzzle HTTP to get data.  When I call a URL in APP1, the action make a call to APP2 and return the response. But If we call through this way, I found that the APP2  uses the .env and database connections of APP1.

To confirm this I added the code in the action of the APP2.

```
return response()->json(['host' => DB::connection()->getConfig("host"), 'env_host' => env('DB_HOST')]);
```

if I call the APP2 url directly on the browser, it return the correct result:

```
{"host":"localhost","env_host":"localhost"}
```

But If I make a REST call over Guzzle HTTP from APP1 to APP2, it returns this response:

```
{"host":"localhostX","env_host":"localhostX"} //where localhostX is the value I added in .env file of APP1
```

This is the guzzle request code:

```
 client = new Client([ 'base_uri' => 'http://localhost/app2/', 'http_errors' => true, 'allow_redirect' => true ]);

        $response = $this->client->request('GET', $uri, []);

        $responseCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $contentType  =  $response->getHeaderLine('content-type');
        $responseBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        dd($responseBody);
```

Can anybody have solution for this ? I think the guzzle makes REST which does not keep session.

I have already referred the question and answer [Getting trouble when sending http request from one laravel project to another in same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097372/getting-trouble-when-sending-http-request-from-one-laravel-project-to-another-in) here. But I didn't see proper solution for the issue.

laravel version : 5.4
laracast link : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-guzzle-http-return-wrong-response

If I place the APP1 and APP2 under different servers (physically separated servers), it works fine as expected!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got the same exact issue.
After some research I have found that the problem is coming from 'phpdotenv'. See this link for more details: [Laravel environment variables leaking between applications when they call each other through GuzzleHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179397/laravel-environment-variables-leaking-between-applications-when-they-call-each-o)

And then I continue my reseach in the issue tracker of 'phpdotenv' and I found this: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/219

> php artisan config:cache is a good suggestion when using laravel;
>   We also need another solution for separated phpdotenv;
>   It is an annoying bugs. Waiting...@_@

For my case, I ended up running "php artisan config:cache" as a temporary solution.

[EDIT]
I have found a better solution on this link, on the last post:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-not-reading-variables-sometimes

So instead of calling the env function anywhere on your application call the function config instead and add the variable in your config section.